# Determining the real reason why WiFi does not connect

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

Often, I try to connect to a Wifi from my Android phones (one is 4.* series, another 6.*), and sometimes it ends with:

- Status: "Saved"
- Status: "Connected, no Internet"

Plus a couple of others, even if the phone(s) report "Signal Strength: Fair" and so on.

So, since the OS does not really tell you a reason why it cannot connect - is there any way to know it?

I guess one could try some of those apps that read logcat on the phone, such as:

- [MatLog Libre](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.pluscubed.matloglibre/)
- [Logcat Reader](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.dp.logcatapp/)

... although they do seem to need root (or special permissions).

Plus, I suspect, some of the times it could be just my phone's radio is too weak to reach the WiFi station (even if the WiFi station's signal is "loud" enough for it to be heard by the phone), and I'm not sure how straightforward it is to reach that conclusion by just reading the data in the logs.

Any ways like that out there?